# WordPress can't change custom menu

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have created a second menu which I'd like to now use as my primary menu on the site (http://ima-mfa.hunter.cuny.edu). However, when I select the new menu it will not show up on the site. If I use another theme it works, so where might I find this problem? Some PHP file?

Comment: u tempered with the code in header,php and removed the code which  display the menus from primary position this could be a problem

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution download [ckeditor](http://ckeditor.com/) its very easy to install and use
 try to use this plugin if you have any trouble in using then let me know i will help you.